# Use AngularJS ng-repeat Filter to Match on Multiple Results?

Tags: angularjs

I've attached ng-model to <select> in AngularJS to narrow the results of my dataset as such:

```
<select ng-model="search_terms.fruit">
 <option>Fruit</option>
 <option ng-repeat="fruit in search_fruits">{{ fruit }}</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="search_terms.color">
 <option>Color</option>
 <option ng-repeat="color in search_colors">{{ color }}</option>
</select>
```

...

```
<div ng-repeat="food in foods | filter:{fruit:search_terms.fruit, color:search_terms.color} | orderBy:orderProp">...</div>
```

Currently this filter shows foods that are both the fruit *and* color that match the filter, but I'd *also* like the filter to match the fruits no matter what color they are when the fruit is selected and "Color" selected for the color (as well as match the color no matter what fruit when the color is selected and "Fruit" selected for the fruit).  Can I do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your custom filter like this:

```
$scope.customFilter = function(searchTerm){
    return function(food){
      //if only one condition is selected
      if(searchTerm.color===null||searchTerm.fruit===null)
      {
        return food.fruit==searchTerm.fruit||food.color==searchTerm.color;
      }else{
        return food.fruit==searchTerm.fruit&&food.color==searchTerm.color;
      }
    };
};
```

Add apply it to your ng-repeat filter. *search_terms is the data object that store the two condition selector's value.

```
<div ng-repeat="food in foods | filter:customFilter(search_terms)">{{food.name}}</div>
```

I think you should use ng-options instead of ng-repeat when you want to render select element's options. ng-repeat will cause some problem:

[image]

```
<select ng-model="search_terms.fruit" ng-options="fruit for fruit in search_fruits">
  <option value="">fruit</option>
</select>
```

**My implementation:**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="search_terms.fruit" ng-options="fruit for fruit in search_fruits">
    <option value="">fruit</option>
  </select>
  <select ng-model="search_terms.color" ng-options="color for color in search_colors">
    <option value="">color</option>
  </select>

  <h3>RESULT</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="food in foods | filter:customFilter(search_terms)">{{food.name}}</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.search_fruits = ["Apple","Orange","Lemon"];
  $scope.search_colors = ["Red","Yello","Green"];
  $scope.foods = [{name:"Apple Pie",fruit:"Apple",color:"Red"},{name:"Lemon tea",fruit:"Lemon",color:"Yello"}];
  $scope.search_terms={color:null,fruit:null};

  $scope.customFilter = function(searchTerm){
    return function(food){
      //if only one condition is selected
      if(searchTerm.color===null||searchTerm.fruit===null)
      {
        return food.fruit==searchTerm.fruit||food.color==searchTerm.color;
      }else{
        return food.fruit==searchTerm.fruit&&food.color==searchTerm.color;
      }
    };
  };
});
```

This is the [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rn3Hy/1/).

Hope this is helpful for you.